# Why does setMenu(null) works on Windows but not on Linux?

Tags: electron

I am calling:

```
mainWindow.setMenu(null);
```

It works on Windows, but not on Linux - the navbar is still showing...

Why?

Answer (score 0):

It only works in electron versions <= 3.0.10

https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/15901#issuecomment-449804054

It's an open bug for linux platforms!

P.S What version of electron are you using?